# Class 'Form' not found in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-facade, laravel-7

## I'm upgrading from Laravel 5 to Laravel 7.

[image]

I'm using a lot of `Form::model` on my project.

> Class 'Form' not found

I tried to install

> "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"

I kept getting

```
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.3.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.3.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.2.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.2.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.2.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.1.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.1.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.0
```

What options do I have now ?

1. replace all Form facade with HTML ? that would be a lot ...
2. add a Form Facade again on this new set up

## Which one do you guys think I should do ?

Comment: Have you tried with `v6` laravelcollective? Check your version with: `composer show -- laravelcollective/html`

Comment: use [laravelcollective/html 6x](https://packagist.org/packages/laravelcollective/html#v6.1.0) instead of `5x`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To support `Laravel` `7.x`, you will need to install version `6.0` of the HTML package. `5.x` Does not support newer versions of `Laravel` after `5.8`. Update your `composer.json`.

```
"laravelcollective/html": "~6.0"
```

After that run.

```
composer install
```

Or simply require it from the command line.

```
composer require laravelcollective/html "~6.0"
```

Comment: Your updated answer works ! `"laravelcollective/html": "~6.0"`

Comment: Thanks @mrhn mrhn. For more information we can visit https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.x/html

Comment: BTW I am using it in Laravel 8.65 version. It works.

Answer (score 20):

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

this dependency removed from laravel

Comment: Yes dear, you are right. we will have to install it by composer `composer require laravelcollective/html "~6.0"` by command line. For more information we can visit https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.x/html